Showing existence of symplectic transformations preserving a quadratic form
Question: I need help to prove the following statement.
Let $W_i:=w_iw_i^T\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$, for $n$ even, be symmetric rank-1 matrices, $J=-J^T$ the canonical symplectic matrix and define the map $\Phi(x) = (I + JW_1)...(I + JW_n)x.$ Then for any symmetric matrix $M=M^T$, there exists $w_1,...,w_n$ (that depend on $M$, and at least one non-zero) such that $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}^n$
$$\Phi(x)^TM\Phi(x)=x^TMx$$
or
$$x^T(I - W_nJ)...(I - W_1J)M (I + JW_1)...(I + JW_n)x=x^TMx$$
Comments:

I have evidence that this is true, that is, I have created many symmetric matrices $M$ and solved for the $w_i$ and found a solution to machine precision.
$M$ can be decomposed into rank-1 matrices by its spectral decomposition: $M=\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i q_iq_i^T$
The matrices $JW_i$ are nilpotent, meaning $(JW_i)^2=0$
The inverse is $(I+JW_i)^{-1}=I-JW_i$
It would be extremely nice if we found explicit formulas for the $w_i$, but I think this is very difficult.
I have written this using the product of $n$ matrices $(I+JW_i)$. I think this is possible but it will also help to do this for more terms in the product.


What is the intended order of your quantifiers? In the first formulation of your question, $M$ is given first and then you ask for the existence of ($M$-dependent) vectors $w_i$. In the reformulation, the $w_i$s are to be the same for all $M$. In both cases, taking $w_i = 0$ for all $i$ is a solution; is there a further constraint on the $w_i$s (e.g. at least one $w_i$ is nonzero)?

Yes, $M$ is given and there must be at least one non-zero, $M$-dependent $w_i$. I have edited the question to clarify.  I thought the reformulation is equivalent to the first, but actually it's not quite. Please only consider the first one

I suppose you still take $M$ to be arbitrary, so that you aim for a statement for any $M$, not just for some $M$? Besides, your problem is still underdetermined: for instance, assuming a solution with a single nonzero $W_1$, then for each integer $k > 1$ we could produce another solution $W'_1 = \dots = W'_k := W_1 /k$.

True, if we could find a single non-zero $W_i$ where this holds, for any $M$, then that would be a useful solution to the problem. I don't think this is possible tho.
And yes I would like to know that there always exists at least one non-zero $W_i$ such that this holds for any arbitrary symmetric $M$. Please let me know if i need to clarify more :)

Let $M$ be a real-valued symmetric $n \times n$ matrix. We want to prove that there exist nonzero (column) vectors $w_1, \dots, w_k \in \mathbb{R}^n$ (with $k \ge 1$) such that setting $W_i := w_i w_i^T$ and $\Phi := \prod_{j=1}^k (I + JW_j)$ (where $J$ is the standard symplectic form), then $M = \Phi^T M \Phi$ (i.e., $\Phi$ is a 'symmetry' of $M$).
First note that if a solution exists, then many others exist, since $(I + JW_j) = (I + J (W_j/N_j))^{N_j}$ for any interger $N_j \ge 1$.
Briefly put, the proof consists in proving that the space of 'symmetries' of $M$ and the Lie group of symplectic matrices necessarily intersect each other along a submanifold of positive dimension, because their respective dimensions are too big compared to the ambient space of all matrices. Moreover, based on this other discussion, we know that any symplectic matrix can be written in the form $\Phi$ claimed above. This proves again that your problem admits a manifold of solutions.
Group of symplectic matrices. These are the matrices $\Psi$ such that $\Psi^T J \Psi = J$. The Lie group of symplectic matrices (aka the symplectic group) $\mathrm{Sp}(2n;\mathrm{R})$ has real dimension $n(2n+1)$.
Space of 'symmetries' of $M$. This is the space of matrices $A$ such that $A^T M A = M$. Since $M$ is a real symmetric matrix, by the spectral theorem, it is orthogonally diagonalizable i.e. the exist an orthogonal matrix $U$ and a diagonal matrix $D$ such that $D = U^T M U$. Setting $B := U^T A U$, we see that $A$ is a 'symmetry' of $M$ if and only if $B$ is a 'symmetry' of $D$.
Consequently, without loss of generality, we can assume $M = D = \mathrm{diag}(d_1, \dots, d_{2n})$ is diagonal. Furthermore, we may assume that $d_i = 0$ iff $i > r = \mathrm{rank}(D)$.
If $D$ is degenerate, its space of 'symmetries' might be a mere semigroup. In spite of this, mimicking the case of Lie groups, we compute the 'Lie semi-algebra' of this space of 'symmetries' to be the set of matrices $B$ such that $B^T D + DB = 0$, i.e. such that $B_{ji}d_{j} + d_{i} B_{ij} = 0$ for all $1 \le i , j \le n$. (The equations associated with the pairs $(i,j)$ and $(j,i)$ are identical, so we may only consider $i \le j$.)

If $i \le j \le r$, then the constraint becomes $B_{ji} = - (d_i/d_j) B_{ij}$. This amounts to $r(r+1)/2$ independent constraints.

If $i \le r < j$, then the constraint becomes $B_{ij} = 0$ (and $B_{ji}$ can be anything). This leads to $r(2n-r)$ independent constraints.

If $r < i \le j$, the constraint is void: $B_{ij}$ and $B_{ji}$ can be anything.


All in all, we have $r(r+1)/2 + r(2n-r)$ constraints, i.e. the space of 'symmetries' of $D$ is at most of codimension $r[2n - (r-1)/2 ]$ with the set of all matrices, hence at most of codimension $2n[2n-(2n-1)/2] = n(2n+1)$ (this last value being achieved iff $r = 2n$).
(As a 'sanity check', note that when $D = Id$, its group of symmetries is the orthogonal group $O(2n)$, which is indeed of codimension $n(2n+1)$.)
Dimensions comparison. If $r < 2n$, we see that the space of 'symmetries' of $M$ is strictly smaller than the dimension of $\mathrm{Sp}(2n)$, so the (tangent spaces at $Id$ of the) two spaces necessarily intersect. Hence there are elements $\Phi \in \mathrm{Sp}(2n)$ that are arbitrarily close to $Id$ such that $\Phi^T M \Phi = M$. As proved in the answer here, any $\Phi \in \mathrm{Sp}(2n)$ is a product of the form $\prod_{j=1}^k (Id + J w_j w_j^T)$ (with $k \le n$ if $\Phi$ is sufficiently close to $Id$).
There remains the case when $r = 2n$, for which the group of symmetries of $M$ has codimension $n(2n+1)$ equal to the dimension of $\mathrm{Sp}(2n)$. This leaves open the possibility that the two groups intersect transversely and only at $Id$ (in which case there would be no 'nontrivial' solution to your problem). For exclude this possibility, a slightly finer analysis is needed.
Since $M$ has full rank, the equation $B^T M B = M$ implies $\mathrm{det}(B) = \pm 1$; let's consider only the (nonempty) component $\mathrm{det}(B) = 1$, which has dimension $(2n)^2 - n(2n+1) = n(2n-1)$. The symplectic matrices $\Psi$ also satisfy $\mathrm{det}(\Psi) = 1$. Hence we can compare these two Lie groups as subgroups of the special linear group $\mathrm{SL}(2n;\mathbb{R})$, which has dimension $(2n)^2 - 1 = (2n+1)(2n-1)$. As a subgroup of $\mathrm{SL}(2n;\mathbb{R})$, the group of symmetries of $M$ has codimension $(2n+1)(2n-1) - n(2n-1) = (n+1)(2n-1) = n(2n+1)-1$, which is strictly smaller than the dimension of $\mathrm{Sp}(2n)$. Hence again, the (tangent spaces at $Id$ of the) two groups necessarily intersect, and so there are elements $\Phi \in \mathrm{Sp}(2n)$ that are arbitrarily close to $Id$ such that $\Phi^T M \Phi = M$, etc.
